# converting string of ascii character decimal values to binary values

Tags: c++, c, binary

I need help writing a program that converts full sentences to binary code (ascii -> decimal ->binary), and vice-versa, but I am having trouble doing it. Right now I am working on ascii->binary.

ascii characters have decimal values.  `a = 97`, `b = 98`, etc. I want to get the decimal value of an ascii character and convert it to a dinary or binary decimal, like 10 (in decimal) in binary is simply:

```
10 (decimal) == 1010 (binary)
```

So the ascii decimal value of a and b is:

```
97, 98
```

This in binary is (plus the space character which is 32, thanks):

```
11000011000001100010 == "a b"

11000011100010 == "ab"
```

I have written this:

```
int c_to_b(char c)
{
    return (printf("%d", (c ^= 64 ^= 32 ^= 16 ^= 8 ^= 4 ^= 2 ^= 1 ^= 0));
}

int s_to_b(char *s)
{
    long bin_buf = 0;

    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        bin_buf += s[i] ^= 64 ^= 32 ^= 16 ^= 8 ^= 4 ^= 2 ^= 1 ^= 0;
    }

    return printf("%d", bin_buf);
}
```

---

**code examples**

main.c

```
int main(void)
{
    // this should print out each binary value for each character in this string
    // eg: h = 104, e = 101
    // print decimal to binary 104 and 101 which would be equivalent to:
    // 11010001100101
    // s_to_b returns printf so it should print automatically
    s_to_b("hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

To elaborate, the `for` loop in the second snippet loops through each character in the character array until it hits the null terminator. Each time it counts a character, it gets does that operation. Am I using the right operation?

Comment: What does "converts full sentences to binary code" mean?

Comment: You may need to narrow this down to something more specific.  Generally "doesn't work, do it for me" isn't very productive.

Comment: Why do you code `c ^= 64`  which means `c = c ^ 64` ? And I don't understand if it is homework, and what is your requirement??

Comment: You might need to re-thing your understanding of character sets.  Everything in a computer is represented in binary, thus ASCII *is* a "binary code" in the sense that every ASCII character is a number represented in binary.  Perhaps you should give an example of the desired transformation as well as a detailed descriptions of how it should work.

Comment: i have updated my post, please refresh the page.  it might give you a better view at what i am trying to do.  this is not homework!

Comment: It is still not understandable. Notice that `printf` returns the number of output characters. Give several examples of the intended behavior (and result) of your `c_to_b` and `s_to_b` functions.

Comment: Your description is still unclear.  It seems there are hidden rules, such as spaces.  A space is character 32 in ASCII, which would give it a binay code of 00100000, making "a b" map to "1100001001000001100010", not "1100001 1100010".

Comment: What output format do you wish to have?  A string of ASCII characters "1" and "0" representing the binary code (assuming output to the standard output is in ASCII)?

Comment: i meant lower case a not uppercase.  lower case a is 97 according to an ascii table i found.  i will edit my post and give examples, now!  i just wrote an example.  hopefully that is good enough.

Comment: Who said anything about uppercase characters?  The space character has value 32 (0100000 in binary) and is not upper case.  Given the input string "a b", concatenating the codes for "a" (1100001), " " (0100000) and "b" (1100010) gives "110000101000001100010".

Comment: sorry i mis-read your comment please ignore what i said directed towards you.  yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like

```
void s_to_b(const char*s)
{
  if (s != NULL) {
     while (*s) {
        int c = *s;
        printf(" %d", c);
        s++;
     }
     putc('\n');
  }
}
```

Comment: yes exactly like this, but i believe it prints out the characters in decimal (it printed values over 1, like 9).  is there a way to make the characters print out in binary rather than decimal?

Comment: Code a function `print_in_binary` and replace the call to `printf` with `print_in_binary(c);`

Comment: here is what i came up with:
int print_in_binary(char c)
        {
            int q = c;
            while ((q / 2) != 0) {
            q = (c / 2);
        }
        printf(" %d", q);
    }

Comment: This probably prints the bits but from last to first. You should put them in an array first, then display in reverse order.